# Being selective with preventDefault

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am creating an Android App. Overall I want to prevent default behaviour. So I use this code snippet:

```
    document.ontouchmove = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

However I am using a multi-page template. With Phonegap and Jquery Mobile. I would like a way to lock default behaviour only on certain divs. Also I was wondering if there is a way to pick and choose certain behaviours. For example I would like to disable horizontal scrolling on some pages whilst maintaining vertical scrolling.

Anyone have any ideas, or can tellme how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I expect that this would work:

```
document.ontouchmove=function(event){  
    if(event.srcElement.className=='donttouch'){
          event.preventDefault();
          // You probably will need to add event.stopPropagation() as well,
          // maybe before.
    } else {
         // Do your thing...
    }
}
```

**note**:  class is probably not the best way to do this.  Data would be better, as classes can be dynamic and problems can arise.